# Can I reset and loop again through MySqlDataReader?

Tags: asp.net, sqldatareader, datareader, mysqldatareader

I have a MySqlDataReader object, with the result of this query :

`SELECT warehouse, leasing, transportation, maintenance, manpower FROM retail WHERE zone =  'Central' GROUP BY warehouse`

And then I loop through the DataReader once,

```
while (r2.Read())
{
strXml.AppendFormat("<set label = '{0}'></set>",r2["warehouse"].ToString());
}
```

And now I want to loop through it again...!!

I know that DataReader is only a 'forward-only' object.. But is there any other solution for me here ?

I'm asking, is there any any efficient way to hold data other than MySqlDataReader ?

Comment: You can again call reader after opening connection ?

Comment: @Saurabh: Opening the connection again ? Then I'll have to run the SELECT query again.. I'm asking, is there any any efficient way to hold data other than MySqlDataReader ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below :

```
using (MySqlConnection connMySql = new MySqlConnection(global.g_connString))
            {
               MySqlCommand cmd = connMySql.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "selece * from <table>"; 
                connMySql.Open();
                using (MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
                        dt1.Load(dr);
                        // You can use this dt1 anywhere in the code
                 }
```

// parsing datatable

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int count = 0; count < dt.Rows.Count; count++)
        {
            string str= dt.Rows[count]["[ColumnName]"].ToString();  
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to DataTable, but now I am unable to find a proper tutorial which would show me how to iterate through it.. I'd like to iterate through the DataTable like I was doing for the DataReader.. just like `r2["warehouse"]` ... Could you help me out that way ?