# Populate a number of DropDownLists with MySQL reader

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, loops, drop-down-menu

I have 10 DropDownLists (ddlQuestion1IDs, ddlQuestion2IDs, ddlQuestion3IDs...) that I want to populate with data from a database.  However, the following code only populates ddlQuestion1IDs.  Why is this and what's the most efficient way to populate all 10 with the same data?

```
protected void getQuestionIDs()
{
    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
    MySqlDataReader reader;

    string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE module_id=@ModuleID";
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ModuleID", MySqlDbType.Int32);
    cmd.Parameters["@ModuleID"].Value = ddlModules.SelectedValue;

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            var ddlQuestion = (DropDownList)FindControl("ddlQuestion" + i.ToString() + "IDs");
            ddlQuestion.DataSource = reader;
            ddlQuestion.DataValueField = "question_id";
            ddlQuestion.DataTextField = "question_id";
            ddlQuestion.DataBind();
            ddlQuestion.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(string.Empty, "blank"));
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
        lblError.Text = "Database connection error - failed to get question IDs.";
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use a single variable instead of always searching the same control? That would be more efficient and - more important - much more readable. `var ddlQuestion = (DropDownList)FindControl("ddlQuestion" + i.ToString() + "IDs"); // set all properties...`

Comment: @TimSchmelter Modified. Thanks though still only the first DropDownList gets populated when I actually want to populate all ten.

Comment: I would use a `MySqlDataAdapter` to fill a `DataTable` and use that as `DataSource`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My wild-ass-guess is that the reader is stream-based, forward-only and the first bind successfully iterates over the data while the subsequent binds find the data stream to be at the end.

I would try copying the data into an array and try binding to the array. Here's a question that might be helpful.

[Can I reset and loop again through MySqlDataReader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6580065/can-i-reset-and-loop-again-through-mysqldatareader)